# How to retrieve the delete icon from the iOS keyboard (using Xcode)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Shown below is the delete icon from tvOS (though the icon exists on iOS keyboard as well):

[image: Delete icon]

However this icon is not available on the storyboard list.

EDIT: Apologies for the low-quality question. If there was no answer, my last resort was to download my own icon; I just wanted to make sure I'm not skipping any simpler method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the keyboard icons fall under private API and are inaccessible to developers.

I don't see why you would want to do this, though. Why not just download your own image that looks identical?

For example, [this one](https://icons8.com/icon/set/clear-symbol/ios).

**Edit:**

iOS 13 added [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/):

> SF Symbols provides a set of over 1,500 consistent, highly configurable symbols you can use in your app. Apple designed SF Symbols to integrate seamlessly with the San Francisco system font, so the symbols automatically ensure optical vertical alignment with text for all weights and sizes. SF Symbols are available in a wide range of weights and scales to help you create adaptable designs.

"Delete left" is one such symbol.

Comment: Thanks. I did end up downloading my own image. I was just unsure if that was the best way.